# Change button state (icon) of Action Bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

How i can dinamically change action button icon of `Action Bar` when i swipe fragments in `ViewPager`. Depending on fragment button must change state (icon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem:
1) I implement `OnPageChangeLister`
2) Invoke `setIcon()` in `onPageScrollStateChanged()`
3) `MenuItem` defined like global variable (field of class)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the correct icon in [onPrepareOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29), and then invalidate your action bar with [invalidateOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29) (or [ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28android.app.Activity%29) if you are using the support library) when you want the icon to update.

For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
  MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.my_menu_id);
  item.setIcon(getMenuItemIconResId());
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
  invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check your solution.